# Roblox studio, не получается сравнить 2 числа

Tags: текст, lua, compare, roblox

Делаю денежную валюту в роблокс, но не срабатывает один скрипт:

```
Local barrier = парт, который не даёт игроку войти в комнату
Part.ClickDetector.mouseclick:connect(function()
    If
game.starterGui.screenGui.TextLabel.text >= 50 then
        Barrier:destroy()
   End
End)
```

Answer (score 0):

`game.starterGui.screenGui.TextLabel.text` - это строка

Сравнение:

```lua
"1" == 1 --false
```

Превратите строку в число:

```lua
tonumber(game.starterGui.screenGui.TextLabel.text) >= 50
```